# how do i invoke 32 bit gdb installed on Centos 64

Tags: gdb

I have Centos7 and I see both 32 and 64 bit version of gdb are installed however /usr/bin/gdb is the 64bit version. How can I invoke 32bit gdb version since i need to debug application compiled with -m32 compiler option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 64-bit GDB is *perfectly* capable of debugging both 64 and 32-bit programs. You don't need to invoke 32-bit GDB.